# How to publish advertisements in a Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, adsense, ads

I have a Chrome App which is currently just a link to a web application. I would like to make this a packaged app, so it is available offline. There is one problem though: I have an Adsense ad on the web application, and Adsense ads are not allowed in Chrome apps.

How to enable ads in a packaged Chrome app?

Comment: old thread, but one year later I am asking myself the same question. Did you work this out ? Care to share your solution ?! Thx...

Comment: Having a link to a web application with ads worked just fine. Until Google disabled all non-packaged chrome apps. There are other advertising platforms which do support ads in packaged Chrome apps, like the one mentioned below, I suppose that's the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This company offers ads for apps/extensions:
http://www.bumblead.com/

This other one has an interesting banner exchange program for apps/extensions:
http://factory.extensionfactory.com/promo/

Also there is some evidence google is working on a solution of their own, but there are no official announcements yet:
https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/hqHFwvZhbDS